# Display Alert Dialog when Activity onPause()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-handler

I am trying to show an alert dialog when a countdown timer finishes and the activity is sent in the background via the `onPause()` method.

I did some research but couldn't find something to fit my needs.

I tried to achieve this by using a handler:

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                int aResponse = msg.getData().getInt("message");
                if (aResponse == DISPLAY_DLG) {
                    showStopAlarmDialog();
                }
            }
        };
```

And in the timer's `onFinish()` method

```
Message msgObj = myHandler.obtainMessage();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("message", DISPLAY_DLG);
msgObj.setData(b);
myHandler.sendMessage(msgObj);
```

However, this still only works when the activity is in the front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the *AlarmManager* for this task. Otherwise you have to be aware of handling a wake lock so the device doesn't goes to sleep, and if the time to elapse is too long then you will hit unnecessary battery drain.

Using the *AlarmManager* to fire an Intent and receive it in your app is the way that has work the better for me. Be sure to set the alarm when the activity goes to **onPause()** and unset the alarm when **onResume()**. You can also check if launching an Activity with Theme.Dialog is gonna suit better to your needs, 'cause if you lose the activity Context you won't be able to display a regular dialog.

Hope this helps.